# Hashicorp python client hvac issue:- "bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed'

Tags: python, ssl, tls1.2, hashicorp-vault

I am using the following config.hcl for my Hashicorp server,

```
disable_mlock = true

storage "file" {
  path = "/etc/secrets"
}

listener "tcp" {
 address     = "10.xx.xx.xx:8200"
 tls_cert_file = "/etc/certs/selfsigned.crt"
 tls_key_file  = "/etc/certs/selfsigned.key"
}
```

it is working fine when i perform vault operations,
But when i try reach it using hvac python library i am getting SSL error.
The code i am using to connect to hashicorp server from python is,

```
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(url='https://10.xx.xx.xx:8200', cert=('/etc/certs/selfsigned.crt', '/etc/certs/selfsigned.key'))
client.token = 'd460cb82-08aa-4b97-8655-19b6593b262d'
client.is_authenticated()
```

The full error trace i am getting is as follows:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1
>   , in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hvac/v1/**init**.py", line
>   552, in is_authenticated
>       self.lookup_token()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hvac/v1/**init**.py", line
>   460, in lookup_token
>       return self._get('/v1/auth/token/lookup-self', wrap_ttl=wrap_ttl).json()   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hvac/v1/**init**.py", line
>   1236, in _get
>       return self.**request('get', url, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hvac/v1/__init**.py", line
>   1264, in __request
>       allow_redirects=False, **_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   512, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   622, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line
>   511, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.xx.xx.xx', port=8200): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /v1/auth/token/lookup-self (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
>   failed')],)",),))

Answer (score 1):

According to hvac documentation [Using TLS with client-side certificate authentication](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#initialize-the-client), you need to specify `verify=server_cert_path` parameter.

Testing as below, i can get results as expected. btw with or without `token` parameter, it could run successfully.

```
import hvac

client = hvac.Client(url='https://127.0.0.1:8200',
                     token='xxxxxxxx',
                     cert=('server.crt',
                           'server.key'),
                     verify='ca.crt')

res = client.is_authenticated()
print("res:", res)
```