# Pythonic way to connect hashicorp vault using self signed certificate

Tags: python, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to connect to hvault using python with self signed cert. I wrote code something like below

```
client = hvac.Client(url='https://localhost:8203', cert=('hv.crt','hv.key'),verify=False)
client.is_authenticated()
client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret(mount_point="secret", path='test')
```

However, it fails with error

```
False
>>> client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret(mount_point="secret", path='test')
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:999: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'localhost'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/uptycs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hvac/api/secrets_engines/kv_v2.py", line 98, in read_secret
    return self.read_secret_version(
  File "/opt/uptycs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hvac/api/secrets_engines/kv_v2.py", line 153, in read_secret_version
    return self._adapter.get(
  File "/opt/uptycs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hvac/adapters.py", line 110, in get
    return self.request("get", url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/uptycs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hvac/adapters.py", line 372, in request
    response = super().request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/uptycs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hvac/adapters.py", line 340, in request
    self._raise_for_error(method, url, response)
  File "/opt/uptycs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hvac/adapters.py", line 258, in _raise_for_error
    utils.raise_for_error(
  File "/opt/uptycs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hvac/utils.py", line 41, in raise_for_error
    raise exceptions.VaultError.from_status(
hvac.exceptions.Forbidden: permission denied, on get https://localhost:8203/v1/secret/data/test
```

When I run same code with token it works

```
client = hvac.Client(url='https://localhost:8203',token='hvs.XXXXXXXX')
client.is_authenticated()
client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret(mount_point="secret", path='test')
```

o/p

```
True
{'request_id': 'fd211543-225f-58d6-4d87-112bec5698b9', 'lease_id': '', 'renewable': False, 'lease_duration': 2764800, 'data': {'data': {'test': 'a'}}, 'wrap_info': None, 'warnings': None, 'auth': None}
```

Even the shell execution is returning the results

```
curl -s -k --header "X-Vault-Token:$(curl -s -k --request POST --cacert cacert.pem --cert hv.crt --key hv.key https://localhost:8203/v1/auth/cert/login | jq -r .auth.client_token)" --request GET https://localhost:8203/v1/secret/data/test |jq -r .data.data[]
```

I went through [link](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_usage.html#making-use-of-private-ca) but there is no defination of the `load_vault_token` across internet for self signed there is one for ec2

Any suggestion?

Comment: The first attempt at instantiating a Vault client provides no authentication, and therefore returns an authorization error. Your second attempt does authenticate. This is the core difference between the two implementations and results, and the self-signed cert aspect is irrelevant at this point (but may become relevant in other code you are implementing outside of the question).

Comment: @MattSchuchard we are using same cert & key to authenticate using the node, we don't provide the token in node too. So I know authentication happens with certs

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60183110/814074 Here he talks about without token also he is able to authenticate but he has not used self-signed

Comment: Looking at the source code, the first thing `Client` [checks](https://github.com/hvac/hvac/blob/a4a972af021eb1e646f12092f5e9bb9f8a0bccfc/hvac/v1/__init__.py#L406) to consider itself authenticated is whether `token` is not falsey. And its initialisation [tries](https://github.com/hvac/hvac/blob/a4a972af021eb1e646f12092f5e9bb9f8a0bccfc/hvac/v1/__init__.py#L68) to take a token from `VAULT_TOKEN` environment variable if one isn't passed. So I think you need to pass a token or configure one regardless.

Comment: Like Matt says, vault requires a token for authentication, regardless of whether it also requires client certificate authentication for TLS. They're not mutually exclusive after all.

Comment: And the fact that the second code ran successfully suggests that either your vault instance doesn't require client certificate auth or that you've set up the enviroment variables `VAULT_CLIENT_CERT` and `VAULT_CLIENT_KEY`, [taken by default](https://github.com/hvac/hvac/blob/a4a972af021eb1e646f12092f5e9bb9f8a0bccfc/hvac/v1/__init__.py#L71) if no `cert` is passed and they're set.

Comment: @EDG956 Yes but I was able to run it without token in Node & Java. So I think  there should be way to do the same in. Even if you see shell script retrived the token using those certs then it used to query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253449/discussion-between-sachin-and-edg956).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I was able to get it working

```
client = hvac.Client(url='https://localhost:8203', cert=('hv.crt','hv.key'),verify=False)
client.login("/v1/auth/cert/login")
if not client.is_authenticated():
  error_msg = 'Unable to authenticate to the Vault service'
  raise hvac.exceptions.Unauthorized(error_msg)

client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret(mount_point="secret", path='test')
```

Thanks @EDG956 for help